# Scrapy Post Request Encoding Different Across Machines

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm fairly experienced in using Scrapy, but came across a new issue today that I can't quite work out. I'm attempting to send a POST request to a website that returns Json data. When I run the script on my primary server the response text is encoded in utf-8 and I am able to load it into Json without any issue.

Porting that same script (and identical project files) over to a new server with all necessary dependencies installed, the response is encoded and I am having difficulty decoding it into utf-8. Any ideas on what environmental variables could be affecting that difference?

Comment: Could you add an example of the responses?

Comment: Is it possible that the response is different? Even if your requests are otherwise identical, sending a request from two different IP addresses can trigger different responses.